# Seasonal package: Forecasts end date [...] must end on or before user-defined regression variables end date

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

I'm relatively new to R and had a question regarding time series format for forecasting and seasonal adjustment using the `seasonal` package. I'm working with `import.spc` to generate function calls based on spec files.

Currently, I have `FORECAST{MAXLEAD=48}`, with my time series ending in `2022-02`. I'm getting this error:

```
- forecasts end date, 2026.Feb, must end on or before user-defined regression variables end date, 2022.Feb.
```

Is this because my time series ends earlier than `2026-02`? I tried appending "NA"s to the end of my historicals but it didn't do much.

Alternatively, I also tried setting `FORECAST{MAXLEAD=0}`, but I ran into this error:

```
Error: X-13 has returned a non-zero exist status, which means that the current spec file cannot be processed for an unknown reason.
```

See my code below:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("seasonal")

fn<-import.spc("C:\\PATH\\TO\\SPEC\\FILE.spc")
x<-import.ts("C:\\PATH\\TO\\DATA\\FILE.dat")
x %>% (fn[1]$seas)
```

FILE.spc

```
SERIES{
TITLE = "Logging"
START = 2016.01
PERIOD = 12
SAVE = (A1 B1)
PRINT = BRIEF
NAME = '1011330000 - AE'
FILE = '"C:\\PATH\\TO\\DATA\\FILE.dat"}
TRANSFORM{FUNCTION = NONE

}
REGRESSION{
USER = (dum1 dum2 dum3 dum4 dum5 dum6 dum7 dum8 dum9 dum10 dum11)
START = 1986.01
USERTYPE = TD
FILE = 'C:\\PATH\\TO\\FILE\\FDUM8606.dat'
SAVE = (TD AO LS TC)
}
ARIMA{
MODEL = (0 1 1)(0 1 1)
}
ESTIMATE{
MAXITER = 3000
}
FORECAST{
MAXLEAD = 0
}
OUTLIER{
CRITICAL = 10.5
TYPES = AO
}
X11{
SEASONALMA = (s3x3)
MODE = ADD
PRINT = (BRIEF)
SAVE = (D10 D11 D16)
APPENDFCST = YES
FINAL = USER
SAVELOG = (Q Q2 M7 FB1 FD8 MSF)
}
```

FDUM8606.dat can be found [here](https://www.bls.gov/web/empsit/ces.spec.other.zip)

FILE.dat

```
2016    2   51.1
2016    3   50.4
2016    4   47.9
2016    5   49.8
2016    6   52.0
2016    7   52.6
2016    8   52.6
2016    9   51.9
2016    10  52.1
2016    11  51.4
2016    12  49.9
2017    1   48.2
2017    2   49.6
2017    3   48.0
2017    4   47.6
2017    5   48.9
2017    6   50.4
2017    7   50.7
2017    8   50.6
2017    9   50.1
2017    10  49.7
2017    11  50.7
2017    12  50.2
2018    1   49.2
2018    2   49.8
2018    3   48.7
2018    4   47.8
2018    5   49.0
2018    6   49.2
2018    7   50.8
2018    8   50.6
2018    9   50.0
2018    10  49.6
2018    11  49.1
2018    12  49.7
2019    1   49.3
2019    2   48.1
2019    3   47.7
2019    4   45.4
2019    5   47.1
2019    6   48.8
2019    7   49.3
2019    8   50.5
2019    9   49.5
2019    10  51.6
2019    11  51.2
2019    12  49.1
2020    1   47.9
2020    2   47.9
2020    3   46.7
2020    4   42.0
2020    5   44.3
2020    6   45.7
2020    7   46.8
2020    8   46.7
2020    9   46.6
2020    10  47.5
2020    11  47.0
2020    12  48.1
2021    1   48.1
2021    2   48.0
2021    3   46.3
2021    4   43.4
2021    5   43.7
2021    6   46.8
2021    7   47.6
2021    8   48.0
2021    9   46.0
2021    10  45.5
2021    11  45.4
2021    12  44.7
2022    1   44.8
2022    2   45.1
```

Comment: How would you expect it to work? It doesn't have a time series model for the other features so it can't extend prediction past the point of your last observation, and if you pass NA's it also can't predict anything since the model doesn't handle NA's, also please post a reprex next time

Comment: I think I did provide a reprex. I provided the 3 lines of code & the .spc and .dat files as well. My understanding is that seasonal can build a forecast, & it doesn’t need any additional features as it’s a time-series model.